Docker compose successfully executed and no warning but table doesn't exist in the database
During the development process, I am struggling to create a working Docker Compose file that can successfully connect the MySQL container and the Spring Boot container.
docker-compose.yml
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://db:3306/${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    networks:
      - springboot-mysql-network
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.36
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - springboot-mysql-network
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      interval: 3s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 10

volumes:
  mysql-data:
networks:
  springboot-mysql-network:
    name: springboot-mysql-network

application.properties
spring.application.name=backend

# Datasource connection
spring.datasource.url=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

# Hibernate
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true

build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.8'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.6'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:3.2.0'
    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.28'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

backend/Dockerfile
FROM openjdk:17-alpine
RUN addgroup -S appuser && adduser -S appuser -G appuser
USER appuser:appuser
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]

When I'm not using a MySQL container and instead use a MySQL instance running on your host machine, the table is created successfully. However, when you try to use a MySQL container, the table creation seems to be failing.

I would inspect the log output of the app's container docker logs CONT.

I don't think there is any issue with your config, as @PeterMmm you should check docker logs. You should check also your application logs.
When container starts, why don't you open a connection to your container and if you have a DB with your expected tables ?? Even from your IDE.

Is the table creation failing and do you get an error at startup? If there is an error please show it, if there isn't and the application does start the table is created and you are looking at the wrong database for verification.

Which tables do you expect to be created and why should they? You didn't post any Entities or repositories, so the problem is not reproducible for me.

I have already fixed the problem. I have changed the configuration in the datasource connection with the following:
# Datasource connection
spring.datasource.platform=mysql
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

Thanks!

If you need to modify settings for normal operation, then the problem description you gave is wrong. : When I'm not using a MySQL container and instead use a MySQL instance running on your host machine, the table is created successfully.

Yeah, my bad. The problem was from the datasource connection configuration.
